# Responsive markers in map design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a design that have an image as a map, there are some absolutely positioned markers on it. The issue is that I want the aspect ration to be the same on the mobile view, so the markers will be in it's place and replacing it with an icon or something.

Please check this image:

[image]

As you see, in the below image the markers are still in the same place. This is how it should look on the mobile. Of course I will replace it with a marker icon because the info is not readable.

HTML:

```
<div class="map">
    <div class="marker">
        <span class="reviews">
             <span class="value">98</span>
             <span>Reviews</span>
        </span>
        <div class="meta">
             <h3>Blue Water</h3>
             <h4>Nice to swim</h4>
        <div class="rating"><span>*</span><span>*</span><span>*</span></div>
    </div>
    </div>           
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.map {
        background: url("../images/thumb.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        height: 650px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: relative;
}
```

Marker code:

```
.marker {
        position: absolute;
        height: 80px;
        left: 100px;
        top: 250px;
}
```

How can we achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could write new CSS rules for specific device resolutions or width and height by using CSS3 media queries.

For example you could add following rule for smaller devices:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .marker {
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        top: 250px;
        background-image: url('icon.png');
    }
}
```

Following link could be useful: ["CSS3 @media Query"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: It won't work because the width and height is different on mobile so we should use percentages or something.

Comment: It should work if you provide @media for various screen sizes. And for each size you can provide different .marker style. 
This could be helpful: [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)